# How can I use Woocommerce $product->get_attribute in functions.php? (if at all)

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to use:
if ( $product->get_attribute( 'pa_orientation' ) == 'vertical') {
// do something
}

in my wordpress functions.php

The goal is to load a style sheet for products when an attribute is matched.

The code above doesn't work. I suspect either it causes an error on non woocommerce pages where the function is not set, or my conditional is not the right type (array?). Does anyone know if $product->get_attribute can be used this way inside functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_attribute()` is a method of the `WC_Product` object, so `$product` needs to be an instance of `WC_Product` that represents the current product. Your code on its own won't work because `$product` is likely not defined.

So you need to define `$product`, but you also need to determine which product it should be defined as. In your case it needs to be the current product when viewing a single product page. You can do this by:

1. Determining if you're on a single product page.
2. If you are, get a `WC_Product` instance of the product that the page is for.

For #1, use `is_product()`, and for #2 use `get_queried_object()` to get a post object for that product, combined with `wc_get_product()` to get the `WC_Product` object for that product.

Altogether that looks like this:

```
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    function() {
        if ( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && is_product() ) {
            $post    = get_queried_object();
            $product = wc_get_product( $post );

            if ( 'vertical' === $product->get_attribute( 'pa_orientation' ) ) {
                // Enqueue your stylesheet.
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Note that I added a check for `function_exists( 'is_product' )`. The `is_product()` function is a WooCommerce function, so your site would crash if WooCommerce was deactivated. Checking for the function before using it prevents that.

Comment: Thanks! I also found a way to do it without functions.php: The widget visibility feature (WP Jetpack) can provide the same conditional. I placed a css link (html widget) in my header widget area and it accomplished the desired result.